# IBAction Button “Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance” Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

I spent a while searching for the answer for this question on google and managed to stumble across the answer myself and thought I would share it.

I was getting the “Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance” Error. I traced it to my button.

What I had done with out realising is assigned two methods to a button. I had made a method and linked it to the button. I then deleted that method made another one and linked it to the button. I didnt realise that the button was still linked and looking to run the old method that was no longer there.

Comment: first share your code :0

Comment: You cant really see the error from the code. I have answered the Question.

Answer (score 6):

Just go to you xib, select button and then in `connectionInspector` **(cmd + option + 6)** delete your previous connection.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this is quite easy. Go on the your storyboard and right click on the button. It will display a list that shows what method it is linked to. If there is more that one there delete all the others that you dont want. This should get rid of that message.

Another thing to note was I was getting a warning that my method had incomplete implementation. I didnt know why that was at the time but it was because there where button methods that werent being implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I got caught by the same problem, and realised that: 
If you delete a function, the links to it in the Interface Builder is still there, you have to manually delete them, or they will link to the non-exist function and raise a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the connection between the button in the main storyboard and the view controller. Then I connected the IBAction-code-snippet to the button instead. That worked.